# bootstrap accordion and jquery nested checkbox functionality

Tags: jquery

I have an bootstrap accordion that has checkboxes nested in them. The issue is on the document ready, I want to check to see if a checkbox in panel1 (.tb1) along with a checkbox in panel2 (.tb3)has been checked. I have code to check it using a :checkbox selector, but that one doesn't work either. The :checkbox selector suppose to trigger at any time.

Any suggestions on how to get either working. The code is below:

```js
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
  if ($("#panel1 .tb1").is(":checked") && $("#panel2 .tb3").is(":checked")) {
    alert("both clicked");
  } else {

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="tb1" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes<br><input type="checkbox"class="tb4" />&nbsp;&nbsp;No<br><br></div><br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="tb3" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes<br><input type="checkbox"class="tb4" />&nbsp;&nbsp;No<br><br></div><br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panel1 checkbox has a class of tb3, not tb1 as you've specified in your jquery code.